# Heatmap Error: Error in cut.default(a, breaks = 100) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, ggpubr, pheatmap

```
library(pheatmap)
df=remove_rownames(g5data2) #var argument specifies the column name that will be used for row names, which in this case is "antibody"

df=column_to_rownames(df, var = "antibody") #Creates a new data frame called my_sample_row containing two rows of values for the "antibody" column, with "Synthetic" and "Native" values being repeated four and six times respectively.

my_sample_col <- tibble(antibody = rep(c("Synthetic","Native"), c(4,6)))
my_sample_col - #Creates a color palette my_colour as a list with two elements named "Native" and "Synthetic" and their respective colors as hexadecimal codes

my_colour = list(antibody = c(Native = "#5977ff", Synthetic = "#f74747"))
my_colour
```

All the above codes work correctly. However when I attempt to create the heatmap:

```
pheatmap(df,annotation_row = my_sample_col,annotation_colors = my_colour)
```

I get error code: `Error in cut.default(a, breaks = 100) : 'x' must be numeric`

I can't seem to find the issue with the code. It worked for a similar task on a project I had last week.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO Jonathan Acosta. As the error states, `pheatmap` is expecting a numeric vector and it's being fed a non-numeric vector. However, sometimes these types of issues can be caused further 'upstream' but diagnosis requires an example of your data.  If you run `dput(g5data2)` and add the result to your question, it'll be easier to give a meaningful answer. If your data are confidential, you can create a replica dataset that reproduces the issue and `dput()` that instead. Thanks